# can't highlight the current menu item/page wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, highlight

I'm trying to edit a menu in wordpress but I can't seem to give the current page menu item the background colour that I want (highlight effect).

When I put in this bit of css...

```
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav a {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index:9999999;
}
```

...the link background went white (which is what I wanted).  Then I added this:

```
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav a:hover {
background-color: #34676b;
}
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav a:active {
background-color: #34676b;
}
```

The `a:hover` works, but `a:active` doesn't.  Next I tried...

```
.current_page_item and .current_page_item a:active
```

...but nothing works, the code below is what I have now and it doesn't work either.  Any help will be much appreciated, hopefully all css (I don't know php).

Thanks,
Lisa

```
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav {
padding-top:30px;
}
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav a {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
z-index:9999999;
}
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav a:hover {
background-color: #34676b;
}
ul#menu-menu-1.nav.navbar-nav li.current_page_item a:focus {
background-color: #34676b;
}
li#menu-item-14.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.current-menu-        item.current_page_item.menu-item-home.menu-item-14.active {
background-color: #34676b;
}
```

Comment: can you share your HTML?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? you're setting the hover and active colors to the same color, so when you click on a link it already has the color, because it's hovered over...
Also, it seems like your [css selectors are too specific](http://css-tricks.com/crazy-town-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, you just want to highlight the current page link?

If so:

```
li.current_page_item a {
    background-color: #34676b;
}
```

Should work.

It searches for the active `<li>` and then styles the `<a>` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem and I used the following code to solve it.

```
li.current-menu-item a {
    background-color: #34676b;
}
```

And just in case you want to change the color of the text once the item menu is selected:

```
li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #34676b;
}
```